# Automapper behavior differs when mapping lists compared to singe objects

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have two objects:

```
public class Person1
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Person2
{
    public string FIRST_NAME { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }
    public int? Foo { get; set; }
}
```

The difference between the two is that the destination object has the additional property named Foo. I would like Automapper to use the destination value of Foo when mapping between a list of Person1 to Person2.

When I map individual objects I can achieve this behaviour. However when I map a collection of Person1 to Person2 the value of Foo is set to null, instead of being equal to 1. Please see my unit test below.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestUseDestValWhenNotFoundIgnore()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Person1, Person2>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FIRST_NAME, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.LAST_NAME, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Foo, opt =>
            {
                opt.UseDestinationValue();
            });

        var personList1 = new List<Person1>();
        var personList2 = new List<Person2>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            personList1.Add(new Person1
            {
                FirstName = "FirtName",
                LastName = "LastName"
            });

            personList2.Add(new Person2
            {
                FIRST_NAME = "",
                LAST_NAME = "",
                Foo = 1
            });
        }


        var sourcePerson = new Person1
        {
            FirstName = "FirstName",
            LastName = "LastName"
        };

        var destinationPerson = new Person2
        {
            FIRST_NAME = "",
            LAST_NAME = "",
            Foo = 1
        };

        // This works as expected, the assert is successful, Foo = 1
        Mapper.Map(sourcePerson, destinationPerson);
        Assert.IsTrue(destinationPerson.Foo == 1);

        // This assert fails, Foo is null for every property
        Mapper.Map(personList1, personList2);
        Assert.IsTrue(personList2.All(p => p.Foo == 1));
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't know how to match up the source object with the target object. Either you need to tell AutoMapper how to match up objects in a list (I haven't really used AutoMapper so I'm not sure if this is possible), or what you're doing doesn't make sense